# Using java functions in scala without import statement

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and learning scala.
I want to understand how in the below code scala is to interpret java code
without any import statement in the scala.
As per my knowledge we can use the java code in scala but we have to import the java package.

```
scala> object Filematcher{
 | private def fileshere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles
 | def fileEnding(query: String)=
 | for (file <- fileshere;
 | if file.getName.endsWith(query))
 | yield file
 | }
defined object Filematcher
```

In this code `new java.io.File(".")).listFiles` 
and
`file.getName.endsWith(query)` are java methods

How scala understand it is java code and it is using it without import package statement.

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both Java and Scala - if you use the **fully-qualified** name of a class (e.g. `java.io.File`, or `scala.collection.Seq`) you don't need the import. Import statements let the compiler know which class you are referring to without having to write its package:

```
import java.io.File

val myFile = new File(".")
```

Lastly - in that respect, there's no difference between calling Java and Scala classes from Scala code - both behave the same. The only difference is that some of Scala's basic classes (e.g. `Int`, `Seq`...) are imported by default into every Scala class.